# Two event listeners doing the same thing (ActionScript 3)

Tags: actionscript-3

Both of my event listeners are going to the same frame, all answers are appreciated.

stop();

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, enterGameClick);
function enterGameClick (event:MouseEvent) {
if (enterGame.alpha == 1){
    gotoAndPlay(4);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, enterGameClick);
}
else if (creditsButton.alpha == 1) {
    gotoAndPlay(3);
    removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, enterGameClick);
}
}
```

Also, is there any way of selecting an object without having to use identification like alpha?

Comment: Silly question, but do you have stop() on frame 3?

Comment: I have a preloader so I knew that wasn't the problem :P

Answer (score 0):

You can get the event.target or event.currentTarget to identify what you should do.